# Custom tableview cell's xib not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I have a custom uitableviewcell and I have code that looks like this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
  defaultCell = [self.listView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DefaultCellIdentifier];
        if(defaultCell){
            defaultCell = [[DefaultCell alloc]init];
        }
```

The if is passed and the default cell is alloced and inited. However, the cell shows up to be blank (the xib file isn't there). I'm registering the nib with the tableview like this -

```
UINib* defaultNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"DefaultCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.listView registerNib:defaultNib forCellReuseIdentifier:DefaultCellIdentifier];
```

So why am I getting a blank view in my table cell instead of what I see in my xib file? I think it's because I'm not allocing the cell with it's xib.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1 - correction in code**
This is the correct way of showing a custom cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method
I learned something today:

*you dont need to check if a cell was dequeued or not because the method will create a new cell from the nib if it can't dequeue one.* - @Abizern,

```
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    //Set the label's data properties that you may have assuming you have a datasource.
    cell.customLabelICreated.text = [myStringsDataSourceArray objectAtIndexPath:index.row];
```

Comment: The correct way is to register the nib for the tableview cell. Then you don't need to check whether a cell was dequeued or not, because the method will create a new cell from the nib if it can't dequeue one.

Comment: @Abizern Please please dont abuse the down voting system in the effort of trying to get the OP to have a look at your post instead. If a small mistake was made in my own answer, please feel free to accommodate and share your knowledge alone. And refer to this link: stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down on how to use the downvoting system. as quoted from stackoverflow: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." – Pavan 1 min ago

Answer (score 0):

you first register your nib for the table view cell like so:

```
 [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"nib name" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:DefaultCellIdentifier];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` . you do not need to alloc the cell explicitly.

Instead you can do something like this

```
defaultCell = [self.listView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DefaultCellIdentifier];

[defaultCell configureCell];//In configure cell method set any images or labels u want.
return defaultCell
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

This call is wrong for two reasons:

```
if(defaultCell){
    defaultCell = [[DefaultCell alloc]init];
}
```

Firstly, it should be `if(!defaultCell)`

Secondly, don't even need to check if a cell was dequeued if you've registered a nib for it. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will always return a cell in this case. All you need to do is configure it.

So, actually, you don't even need this little block of code at all.

Comment: Please please dont abuse the down voting system in the effort of trying to get the OP to have a look at your post instead. If a small mistake was made in my own answer, please feel free to accommodate and share your knowledge alone. And refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down on how to use the downvoting system. as quoted from stackoverflow: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an `egregiously sloppy`, `no-effort-expended` post, or an answer that is `clearly` and perhaps `dangerously incorrect`."

Comment: @Pavan a) Your answer is incorrect (IMHO) because he has already registered the nib for the cell, and you don't need to do the checks. and b) get a grip, mate.

Comment: Yes my method which I learned from an online source happened to be incorrect. Please dont abuse the down vote system only to try to attract the OP to your answer. As i said earlier on, if someone's made a small/great error its best that you can push them in the right direction instead of killing them off :) I'll correct my post. I'll get a grip soon as people like you stop bullying others.

Comment: "Bullying"? I pointed out in a comment what I thought you had done wrong.

Comment: Sure, no problem. 
Thank you @abizern for outlining where I had gone wrong. Bye now.